# Proving question on distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Show that if $X = \text{exponential}(1)$, then $Y = X/\lambda$ is $\text{exponential}(\lambda)$.

Need help with solving this one.
I have tried:
$$P(X\leq  x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$$
therefore 
$$P(Y) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x/\lambda} = 1- e^x.$$
Now by differentiating to get the PDF equal to $e^x$.

Comment: In the CDF for X, you are using $\lambda$ as the parameter, instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y\le y)&=& P\left\{\dfrac{X}{\lambda}\le y\right\}\\
&=&P\left\{X\le\lambda y\right\}\\
F_{Y}(y)&=&1-e^{-\lambda y}\\
f_{Y}(y)&=&\lambda e^{\lambda y}
\end{eqnarray*}$